# MySQL: replace all foreign characters in a string

Tags: mysql, string, replace, diacritics

for MySQL, does someone know of the quickest way to replace all foreign characters in a string with their 'normal' equivalent like `ë` to `e` ?

I'm using a multiple REPLACE function now, but I have the feeling it's getting really slow...

Comment: Not all "foreign" characters have direct 1-to-1 mappings to "normal" characters (the concept of "normal" being somewhat dubious).  If you do this you're discarding information.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because some of the people use the foreign characters and some do not. In Dutch we have certain words that have an ë but some people are too lazy to write it... (or don't know how to, because it's not on a dutch keyboard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that, rather than discard relevant information, you want to use a collation that ignores these differences during comparison.  You need an "accent-insensitive" collation, which I believe MySQL provides.

Comment: You're right. The collation I use now (utf8_general_ci) even does that already!  I thought it didn't...